# AWS Beanstalk AutoScaling Latency

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Could someone help me find the optimal settings to make my Windows Beanstalk Enviroment add a new instance when the application latency is more then two seconds and take it down under a second.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggested to start from finding answer on following questions:
1. How long takes adding new instance;
2. How much request can handle you current configuration.
3. What is the load pattern for you application? 
These answers will help you to choose optimal autoscalling configuration: if you adding new ec2 instance takes significant time you need to have low threshold when you need to start scaling up, 
or if you know time when load increases you can add additional instances by scheduler etc.